# REDIS how to remove Expiry from a key

Tags: redis

I have searched fair enough to conclude that such question was not asked yet.

Let's Suppose we have a REDIS SET KEY:

```
SET TEST_KEY 1
TTL TEST_KEY ## -1 (unlimited)
EXPIRE TEST_KEY 1000 # 1
TTL TEST_KEY ## 1000 (1000 seconds)
```

Let's say now I wish to remove the expiry from this specific key so's `TTL` would return `-1`, what to do ?
I have tried setting the `EXPIRE` to `-1` but it didn't work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just reset it with the `SET` command:

```
SET TEST_KEY 1
TTL TEST_KEY  ## -1
```

A more general command, which also works with `LIST`, `SET` and so on, is `PERSIST`

```
PERSIST TEST_KEY
TTL TEST_KEY   ## -1
```

Comment: and what if it was a list ?

Comment: You saved my life

Answer (score 9):

### Use PERSIST commmand

```sh
redis> SET mykey "Hello"
"OK"
redis> EXPIRE mykey 10
(integer) 1
redis> TTL mykey
(integer) 10
redis> PERSIST mykey
(integer) 1
redis> TTL mykey
(integer) -1
redis>
```